# Vue typescript router.Push() just changes address but not reloading page

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

Hello there everyone.

I m asking this strange question because of one factor:

Whenever I'm trying to change route in my app is just changes adress in bar, but not reloading page.
My code is just basic implementation of vue router. Routes do not even change if i write adress to my web browser bar and click enter, It just refresh when i manualy refresh page (same scenario when i use @click, it changes adress but not reloading page, until i would do it manually)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "welcome" */ '@/views/Welcome.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/face',
    name: 'faceHeal',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "welcome" */ '@/views/FaceHeal.vue')
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

export default router
```

If it can helps, i m using typescript

Comment: Are you injecting the router into the app? This is where you declare `new Vue({ .. }).mount(#app)`

Comment: @JamesTotty Yes, I m: new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

Comment: I have the same problem